# PHP Declare method in class if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, methods

In PHP, is it possible to declare a method in a class only if a statement is true :

```
class MyClass {

    //...
    
   
    if (mode === 'production'):
    public function myMethod() {
        // My cool stuffs here        
    }
    endif;
}
```

Comment: No it isn't ...

Comment: No, but you can certainly solve whatever problem you are trying to solve some other way.  For example you could use inheritance, or a factory pattern, or perhaps pass an object into the class that either does or does not have the method defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, but there are certainly some alternative solutions like using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

> You can limit your function work by creating `object` and calling the
> `method` of your `class` through your condition. For example,

```
class MyClass {
    public function myMethod() {
        // My cool stuffs here
        return 'Hello there';
    }
}

$myObj = new MyClass();
$mode = 'production';
if ($mode === 'production'):
    echo $myObj->myMethod();
endif;
```

> Even you can use the constructor method and pass the `$mode` value and
> then return value only condition is true.

```
class MyClass {
    private $mode;
    function __construct($mode) {
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }
    public function myMethod() {
        // My cool stuffs here
        if($this->mode == 'production'){
            return 'Hello there';
        }
        return '';
    }
}

$myObj = new MyClass('production');
echo $myObj->myMethod();
```